# Chrome console logging - Javascript

Tags: javascript, console

I'm wondering, why do some elements appear like an array and others like HTMLSpanElement. I've attached a picture as I'm not sure how to describe this otherwise.

The following log is made via

```
log(returner);
log(returner[0]);
```

[image: console logging]

Comment: returner is `window.getElementsByClassName('doi');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is returner a jQuery object as a result of $() ?  $() will always return an array, even if there is one or zero elements inside of it.  Without specifying an index in your first console.log, the entire contents of the array are outputted.  In the second console.log, you include an array index, so only the element matching that index is outputted.

Comment: More generally, the OP is comparing an array `returner` with an element in the array `returner[0]`.  jQuery is moot.  (though I agree the likely originator)

Answer (score 1):

Because the element that appears like an array IS an array - it's an array of DOM element objects (HTMLSpanElement, etc).

When you log the first element of the array with `returner[0]`, that element is a DOM object, so it logs it as an object.

Answer (score 1):

Because (it looks like) `returner` is not an element, but an array of elements.